# Can OpenSSH 6.7 optionally not depend on OpenSSL?

Tags: openbsd, openssl, openssh, cryptography

It has been [reported on Slashdot on 2014-04-30 that OpenSSH now has a compile-time option to not depend on OpenSSL](http://it.slashdot.org/story/14/04/30/1822209/openssh-no-longer-has-to-depend-on-openssl).

However, [OpenSSH 6.7 release notes](http://www.openssh.com/txt/release-6.7), released on 2014-10-06, do not make any mention of any such option.  Nonetheless, the option is still present in [Makefile.inc](http://bxr.su/OpenBSD/usr.bin/ssh/Makefile.inc).

What happened?  Perhaps the option is only available or tested in the non-portable version of OpenSSH, and that's why it's not being advertised?  Or has it been found not to work?  Or it is for development or testing purposes only, after all?  Too complicated for the users to follow?  Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

OpenSSH (including portable version) doesn't depend any more on OpenSSL nor LibreSSL for that matter.